# How to scrape website with filling some input text and click submit button in .NET Core C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, .net-core, buttonclick, simulate

I am scraping a website which is done in classic asp.net. It has 2 fields with ID. One is input text and another one is a Button. I need to fill in the input box and click the button. And also get the response. The button is a Submit type.

I was using HTML Agility pack. But it's not sufficient with filling the input box and click the button.

Example of the code is :
'

```
            <table class="MainTable">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="styleIndent">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="Labels"><span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblLastName" class="fieldHeader" for="ctl00_MainContent_txtLastName">Name:</span></td>
                    <td class="styleColumnBody">
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtLastName" type="text" value="sberbank" maxlength="250" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtLastName" tabindex="2" title="Enter name as search criteria." style="width:200px;">
                    </td>
                    <td class="Labels"><span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblCity" class="fieldHeader" for="ctl00_MainContent_txtCity">City:</span></td>
                    <td class="styleColumnBody">
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtCity" type="text" maxlength="250" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtCity" tabindex="6" title="Enter city name as search criteria." style="width:200px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="Labels"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left">
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch" value="Search" id="ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch" tabindex="9" style="font-weight:normal;height:22px;width:96px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnReset" value="Reset" id="ctl00_MainContent_btnReset" tabindex="10" style="font-weight:normal;height:22px;width:96px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

'

It's a Classic .Net where the page is reloaded on a button click (**ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch**). So it's hard to know anything by inspecting the page:

Comment: I think jQuery could solve this issue pretty easily. If you have the Id's you can just grab the elements by them. Something like "$('#buttonId').Click();" and "$('#inputId').Val('SOMEVAL');"

Comment: @Dortimer I am not using JQuery. That's why it's a bit difficult. I am working on rest API using dotnet core

Answer (score 2):

Html Agility Pack is designed to parse, query and manipulate the HTML DOM. Some kind of crawlers would be a use-case for it. But you want to acually *run* the http request, javascript-event or whatever is behind those button. The easiest method with most features is to remote-control a webbrowser.

First install Selenium and a browser-driver. I'm using Firefox here since it's free, open source and keep an eye on privacy:

```
Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver
Install-Package Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver
```

Download the driver executable of your browser. Firefox gecko driver could be found on github here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64.zip Version overview if post get older: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Now execute the archive and copy it's path to a variable:

```
string geckoDriverPath = @"D:\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64";
```

We're ready to start using Firefox. A simple example that enter some query in the search field of stackoverflow and click the search-button on the right:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string geckoDriverPath = @"D:\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64";
        using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver(geckoDriverPath)) {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");
            var searchBox = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#search .js-search-field");
            searchBox.SendKeys("Selenium");

            var searchButton = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#search .js-search-submit");
            searchButton.Click();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Please be patient, it can take a few seconds to initialize the browser.

Depending on what your button click is doing, there may be other ways. If it is some kind of http request (form or ajax call), you could send it manually. This is faster, saves ressources and you can run it headless easily. But it's harder to realize. Especially on complex pages where you need to extract data like ids from the page source. You may consider this if you care about performance and ressources.

Comment: Yeah, I have done that. But I don't want to use selenium.

Comment: there is a smarter way for path:
var chrome = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options)

Comment: Sure, depending on the deployment there are smarter ways. But the short question only ask for automatically filling, what my POC does. Also the question only mention that Html Agility Pack isn't working. No information that you already tried Selenium and why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Lion12 Yeah true, My mistake! Html Agility pack is working but in this context, it's not sufficient. As i have to set the value of an input box and click the button. And also note that it's an asp.net website. That means there is no rest API call. And the page reloads when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

How about using headless chrome? you can navigate to web page and do any operation as you please.

https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp

```
// lauch browser and save in variable
var _browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    ExecutablePath = _config.ChromePath, // get path to chrome executable
});
// go to page
var _page = await _browser.NewPageAsync();
var page.GoToAsync("http://www.example.com");

// click on form input 
await _page.ClickAsync("#name");
// set data
await _page.Keyboard.SendCharacterAsync("John");
// submit form
await _page.ClickAsync("#SubmitButton");
```

Comment: @Nice idea. I have tried this. And it was working. I was using selenium. I don't know Puppeteer. Is that good to use here..?

Comment: Yes it works well. I have used in my projects and it works well. I was also filling a form and getting data from the pages.

Comment: Thanks! But there is dependency with chrome executable. We should have chrome.

Comment: Would this work as a server solution (e.g. running on Azure)?

Comment: @NorbertKardos Yea for example I had one running on virtual machine and making a socket connection to it so it's totally fine

Answer (score 0):

If the form is a standard HTML form, you can obtain the post-back url and then post the form data yourself. In essence, you are performing the action that the button would normally do instead of filling out the form itself.

To get this to work you need the URL that is being posted to, and the name of the elements that are getting posted back to the server. You can easily obtain this through any web inspector tools. Once you have it, you can do the below:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post.ToString();
request.ContentType = "application/json";

// replace name1, name2, value1, value2 with the 
// key value pairs that need to be posted.
var content = $"{name1}={value1}&{name2}={value2}"

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(content);
}

request.ContentLength = content.Length;
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encoding))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using .NET 4.5 or above you can use the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient) class which makes this a lot simpler:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data));

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that (HttpClient). But i couldn't figure it out. Or it wasn't working. Please note that I want to set the value of an element by ID ("ctl00_MainContent_txtLastName")

Comment: May be I am missing: How to set up the data for the post request.

Comment: Open a web inspector, fill out the form and then look at the request that is being submitted. You need to ensure the body content is in the format that it is expecting - the easiest way to do this is to copy the one that is generated by the form itself. Both of the examples above are taken from running production code that I have, so I know that these work.

Comment: Hi, It is an asp.net button. That means it reloads the page when you click on it. And there is an even function on the server side. Example of the code is in the question now. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you need to install the Selenium WebDriver NuGet package in your project. You can do this from the NuGet console with the following command:

   Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver
2. In your controller, you can define an action that receives the ID number to search and uses Selenium WebDriver to navigate to the search page, fill out the form, and get the results. Here is an example of what this action might look like:

   ```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var userAgent = HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult Search(string dni)
    {
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("headless");
        options.AddArgument("disable-gpu");
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        try
        {
            // Navegar a la página de búsqueda
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://eldni.com/pe/buscar-por-dni");

            // Llenar el formulario con el número de DNI
            var inputElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("dni"));
            inputElement.SendKeys(dni);

            // Hacer clic en el botón de búsqueda
            var buttonElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(@class, 'btn-success')]"));
            buttonElement.Click();

            //// Esperar a que la página de resultados cargue completamente
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement resultsElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("div-copy")));

            // Obtener los resultados
            string nombre = resultsElement.FindElement(By.Id("nombres")).GetAttribute("Value");
            string apellidop = resultsElement.FindElement(By.Id("apellidop")).GetAttribute("Value");
            string apellidom = resultsElement.FindElement(By.Id("apellidom")).GetAttribute("Value");

            // Devolver los resultados en la vista
            return Json(new { Nombre = nombre, ApellidoP = apellidop, ApellidoM = apellidom });
        }
        finally
        {
            // Cerrar el navegador
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
   ```
3. In your view, you can display the results obtained in the previous step:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchButton").click(function () {
            var dni = $("#dni").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Controller/Search?dni=" + dni,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#resultado").html(
                        "<br><br>" +
                        "<h3>RESULTADO</h3>" +
                        "<table class='table-bordered table-striped' style='width: 100%' >" +
                        "<thead><tr><th>NOMBRES</th><th>A. PATERNO</th><th>A. MATERNO</th></tr></thead>" +
                        "<tbody><tr><td>" + data.Nombre + "</td><td>" + data.ApellidoP + "</td><td>" + data.ApellidoM + "</td></tr></tbody>" +
                        "</table>"
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="dni">DNI: </label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="dni" name="dni" maxlength="8" value="@Model" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton">Consultar Datos</button>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

I hope to be helpful. Greetings